# Initialization with null-coalescing operator?

Tags: c#

I may not have a good grasp of the **?? operator** yet and ran into a design flaw I couldn't explain.

Compare the following two properties, the only difference being how there are initialized: the first explicitly initialized, while the second with the ?? operator (or am I doing it wrong here?).

If I run data init with both properties, the collection based on the first property comes up populated as expected, while the second one with the **?? operator** never gets populated and comes up with 0 elements in the collection.

Surely something is wrong here in my assumption; what is the flaw here?

P.S. Please ignore the **Set** method which is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the base class and has no bearing on this issue (which is confined to the type of initialization).

// property version 1

```
private ObservableCollection<UserName> _userNameColl = new ObservableCollection<UserName>();
public ObservableCollection<UserName> UserNameColl
{
    get { return _userNameColl; }
    set { Set(ref _userNameColl, value); }
}
```

// property version 2

```
private ObservableCollection<UserName> _userNameColl;
public ObservableCollection<UserName> UserNameColl
{
    get { return _userNameColl ?? new ObservableCollection<UserName>(); }
    set { Set(ref _userNameColl, value); }
}
```

// a simple class for creating object collection

```
public class UserName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

// a simple test populating the collection

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    // silly data init just for test

    UserNameColl.Add(new UserName()
    {
        Name = $"UserName No {i}",
        Age = 20 + i,
        Email = $"email{i}@local.lan"
    });
}
```

Comment: The second one never actually sets the value of the inner collection unless you set it manually, so unless you do it will return a new `ObservableCollection` instance every time you try to get it.

Comment: Aaaah! That explains it.

Answer (score 5):

The second one never initializes your field but always returns a new collection. Try this one instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserName> UserNameColl
{
    get { return _userNameColl ?? (_userNameColl = new ObservableCollection<UserName>()); }
    set { Set(ref _userNameColl, value); }
}
```

Comment: The `??` operator has a confusing precedence, but you need to surround the assignment in parentheses before this will compile.

Comment: Of course! It's crystal clear when you know the answer and I can see it clearly!! Thank you. My FLAW is that I never set the value for _userNameColl  and simply returning an instance. How silly is that!